# A class that is ready to receive messages from another user interface

Tags: c#

I have a form that sends the path of a file to a class and the class processes that file. Now I want to create a button on the form, and by pressing that, class force to stop processing the file.

```
namespace oarch.xmlSql
{
public partial class ReadXMl : Form
{
    
    public ReadXML()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}   

.....

public buttiClick()
{
  classes.ParseXlM(FileNameStr, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(eCodepage),listBox1,listBox2, label6);
}
}
```

here is the class

```
namespace oarch.classes
 {
  public class ParseXlM
  {
    public static DataTable ParseXlM2(string dbfFile, System.Text.Encoding readingEncoding,ListBox olistBox1,ListBox elistBox, System.Windows.Forms.Label nlabel)
    {
    ....
    for (int i =0 ;;)
       {
        .....
        here want to break the loop
       }
     } 
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you have, in addition to describing it. Then show what you tried to achieve your goal and explain how it fails. This is [ask].

Comment: you should use Task and CancellationTokenSource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Comment: "the class processes that file." this is a crucial part of the entire problem you are trying to solve. We really need to see that code to be able to help you. If you are doing it in a loop, then it is probably possible to cancel it, but if you are trying to save a huge string at once (which will take its time) then you probably can forget it and you would need to rewrite your code

Comment: Without showing some code, you won't get proper help

Answer (score 0):

Based on limited description, I see that you can try Cancellation Token pattern. Cancellation Token can be just shared bool field that indicate that processing of the file should be stopped. Token can be set to true after pressing the button. And you need to check this token in some loop in the class that process the file. If token is false continue processing if token is true class should stop processing the file.

Comment: Why bother with a bool if you can actually pass a CancellationToken?

Comment: I just describe the idea. Of course you can use CancellationToken if you need to.